# Substitute the n-th occurrence of a word in vim

Tags: regex, vim, sed, substitution

I saw other questions dealing with the finding the n-th occurrence of a word/pattern, but I couldn't find how you would actually substitute the n-th occurrence of a pattern in vim. There's the obvious way of hard coding all the occurrences like

```
:s/.*\(word\).*\(word\).*\(word\).*/.*\1.*\2.*newWord.*/g
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Apparently there is in sed, but not vim `s///`: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/replace-nth-occurrence-on-each-line-like-sed-td1169460.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this a little more simply by using multiple searches. The empty pattern in the `:s/pattern/repl/` command means replace the most recent search result.

```
:/word//word//word/ s//newWord/
or
:/word//word/ s/word/newWord/
```

You could then repeat this multiple times by doing `@:`, or even `10@:` to repeat the command 10 more times.

Alternatively, if I were doing this interactively I would do something like:

```
3/word
:s//newWord/r
```

That would find the third occurrence of *word* starting at the cursor and then perform a substitution.

Comment: Hrm, there are still a number of problems with this, if the first word is the word we're looking for, '3/word' will get us to the 4th occurrence. Also, when I tried the substitution after finding the n-th instance, it still substitutes the first occurrence.

Comment: `3/word` will find the third occurrence starting at the cursor. Go to the top of the file with `gg` if you want to start there. Note that `3/word` is equivalent to typing `/word` three times so it definitely finds the third occurrence.

Comment: -1: Neither of these work for me if all the words are on the same line (which is what I assume the OP means).  In both examples the substitution still happens to the first word on the line.

Answer (score 10):

For information,

```
s/\%(\(pattern\).\{-}\)\{41}\zs\1/2/
```

also works to replace 42th occurrence. However, I prefer [the solution given by John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073865/substitute-the-n-th-occurrence-of-a-word-in-vim/3073892#3073892) which is more simple -- even if it will not limit itself to the current line.

Comment: @ Luc Hermitte: could you please tell me what does the '\%' mean in your answer. It seems it's an operator that VIM cannot recognize.

Comment: It's like `\(`, but it tells to not bind what is matched by the parenthesis to `\1`. See `:h /\%(`, IIRC

Answer (score 7):

Replace each N<sup>th</sup> occurrence of PATTERN in a line with REPLACE.

```
:%s/\(\zsPATTERN.\{-}\)\{N}/REPLACE/
```

Comment: Could you tell me `zs` and `{N}` are the grammar of  regular expressions or the grammar of vim?

Comment: the Zoom anchors are Vim specifc AFAIK (other languages IDK), see [this great answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3039/7940) about `\zs`  or type `:h \zs` in Vim to get information about it, the `{}` is used in most languages but in different functionalities which mostly is used for length of match or times of occurrence of a pattern or a group match `(....){N}` as like here I used.

Answer (score 2):

To replace the nth occurrence of PATTERN in a line in vim, in addtion to the above answer I just wanted to explain the pattern matching i.e how it is actually working for easy understanding.

> So I will be discussing the `\(.\{-}\zsPATTERN\)\{N}` solution,

The example I will be using is *replacing the second occurrence of more than 1 space in a sentence(string)*.
According to the pattern match code->

1. According to the zs doc,

   `\zs` - Scroll the text horizontally to position the cursor at the start (left 
   side) of the screen.
2. `.\{-}` 0 or more as few as possible (*)

   Here . is matching any character and {} the number of times.
   e.g ab{2,3}c here it will match where b comes either 2 or 3 times.

   In this case, we can also use `.*` which is 0 or many as many possible.
   According to vim non-greedy docs, "{-}" is the same as "*" but uses the shortest match first algorithm.
3. `\{N}` -> Matches n of the preceding atom

   `/\<\d\{4}\>`  search for exactly 4 digits, same as /\<\d\d\d\d>

   **ignore these `\<\>` they are for exact searching, like search for fred -> `\<fred\>` will only search fred not alfred.
4. `\( \)` combining the whole pattern.
5. PATTERN here is your pattern you are matching -> `\s\{1,}` (\s - space and {1,} as explained just above, search for 1 or more space)

> "abc subtring def"
>
> ```
>     :%s/\(.\{-}\zs\s\{1,}\)\{2}/,/
> ```
>
> OUTPUT -> "abc subtring,def"

```
# explanation: first space would be between abc and substring and second 
# occurence of the pattern would be between substring and def, hence that 
# will be replaced by the "," as specified in replace command above.
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers your actual question, but not your intent.

You asked about replacing the nth occurrence of a word (but seemed to mean "within a line").  Here's an answer for the question as asked, in case someone finds it like I did =)

For weird tasks (like needing to replace every 12th occurrence of "dog" with "parrot"), I like to use recursive recordings.

First blank the recording in @q

```
qqq
```

Now start a new recording in q

```
qq
```

Next, manually do the thing you want to do (using the example above, replace the 12th occurrence of "dog" with "parrot"):

```
/dog
nnnnnnnnnnn
```

delete "dog" and get into insert

```
diwi
```

type parrot

```
parrot
```

Now play your currently empty "@q" recording

```
@q
```

which does nothing.

Finally, stop recording:

```
q
```

Now your recording in @q calls itself at the end.  But because it calls the recording *by name*, it won't be empty anymore.  So, call the recording:

```
@q
```

It will replay the recording, then at the end, as the last step, replay itself again.  It will repeat this until the end of the file.

TLDR;

```
qq
q
/dog
nnnnnnnnnnndiwiparrot<esc>
@q
q
@q
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do `/gc` then you can count the number of times it asks you for confirmation, and go ahead with the replacement when you get to the nth :D

Comment: Yup, but I want to substitute the n-th occurrence without the confirmation (like if I had to write a script to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Two regex do the job as initially intended:

`%s/^\(.\{-}word\)\{3}\zs/*` for each line, OR

`%s/\(word\(\_.\{-}word\)\{15}\)\zs\(\_.*\)/*\3` for whole document, followed by:

`%s/word\*/newword`

Note that can change `\{3}` and `\{15}` for desired occurrence number, as well as the match `word`.