# How to replace the second same word in vim

Tags: vim

For example `function(null,null,10)`, How to change to `function(null,10,10)`?
I used

> %s/(function(null,)null/\110

to achieve the same, I want to know more abstract method that can replace the second to any number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

`:%s/\(\zsnull.\{-}\)\{2}/REPLACE/`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901621/2541070

Answer (score 0):

This line will change the 2nd parameter into `10`, without checking if the first parameter is `null` or something else. (You didn't ask for that in your question):

```
s/function(\S*,\zs[^,]*\ze,/10/
```